# Convert played matches to league table

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, html-table, statistics

I play an online FIFA tournament since everyone is safe inside. I want to convert the results to a league table. But I don't know what is the best way to do that.

The data I have is:

```
matches = [
        [{
            "homeTeam": "A",
            "awayTeam": "B",
            "homeGoals": 0,
            "awayGoals": 3
        },
        {
            "homeTeam": "D",
            "awayTeam": "C",
            "homeGoals": 0,
            "awayGoals": 3
        }],
        [{
            "homeTeam": "D",
            "awayTeam": "B",
            "homeGoals": 0,
            "awayGoals": 2
        },
        {
            "homeTeam": "A",
            "awayTeam": "C",
            "homeGoals": 0,
            "awayGoals": 1
        }]
    ];
```

The statistics I want to display are: number of matches played, won, lost & drawn. Goals scored and goals against.
I have a React based web app where I display the results of the matches played.
I host the web app through Firebase so I can use firestore, but is it the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure its fine to use Firebase. To do this I would create a class that generates the required data-structure and include the needed functions there to manipulate the data.

#### League.js

```
class League {
  constructor(matches) {
    this.matches = matches;
    this.table = {};
  }

  getStandings() {
    this.matches.forEach(match => {
      const { homeTeam, awayTeam } = match;

      // add teams to the table
      if (!this.table[homeTeam]) this.addToTable(homeTeam);
      if (!this.table[awayTeam]) this.addToTable(awayTeam);

      // increase the played counter
      this.increasePlayed([homeTeam, awayTeam]);
      // calculate won,lost, drawn
      this.setResults(match);
      // calculate goalsScored and goalsAgainst
      this.setGoals(homeTeam, match.homeGoals, match.awayGoals);
      this.setGoals(awayTeam, match.awayGoals, match.homeGoals);
    });
    // all is done; return the table
    return this.table;
  }

  addToTable(team) {
    this.table[team] = {
      played: 0,
      won: 0,
      lost: 0,
      drawn: 0,
      goalsScored: 0,
      goalsAgainst: 0
    };
  }

  increasePlayed(teams) {
    teams.forEach(team => this.table[team].played++);
  }

  setResults(match) {
    const {
      homeTeam, awayTeam, homeGoals, awayGoals
    } = match;

    if (homeGoals > awayGoals) {
      this.table[homeTeam].won++;
      this.table[awayTeam].lost++;
    } else if (homeGoals < awayGoals) {
      this.table[awayTeam].won++;
      this.table[homeTeam].lost++;
    } else {
      this.table[homeTeam].drawn++;
      this.table[awayTeam].drawn++;
    }
  }

  setGoals(team, scored, against) {
    this.table[team].goalsScored += scored;
    this.table[team].goalsAgainst += against;
  }
}

module.exports = League;
```

Then wherever you need the League, create an instance of it with `matches` parameter, then simply call `getStandings()` function to figure and return the table.

#### app.js

```
const League = require('./League');
// note that all of the matches objects are flat
const matches = [
  {
    homeTeam: 'A',
    awayTeam: 'B',
    homeGoals: 0,
    awayGoals: 3
  },
  {
    homeTeam: 'D',
    awayTeam: 'C',
    homeGoals: 0,
    awayGoals: 3
  },
  {
    homeTeam: 'D',
    awayTeam: 'B',
    homeGoals: 0,
    awayGoals: 2
  },
  {
    homeTeam: 'A',
    awayTeam: 'C',
    homeGoals: 0,
    awayGoals: 1
  }
];

const league = new League(matches);
const standings = league.getStandings();

console.log(standings);
```

Now running **app.js** would output:

```
{
  A: {
    played: 2,
    won: 0,
    lost: 2,
    drawn: 0,
    goalsScored: 0,
    goalsAgainst: 4
  },
  B: {
    played: 2,
    won: 2,
    lost: 0,
    drawn: 0,
    goalsScored: 5,
    goalsAgainst: 0
  },
  D: {
    played: 2,
    won: 0,
    lost: 2,
    drawn: 0,
    goalsScored: 0,
    goalsAgainst: 5
  },
  C: {
    played: 2,
    won: 2,
    lost: 0,
    drawn: 0,
    goalsScored: 4,
    goalsAgainst: 0
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!